# Does rain increase any dangers in marshes and swamps? Or are they dangerous enough that rain doesn't add (or only adds minorly) to their danger?

Tags: rain, swamps

Suppose you knew it was going to be raining and you had to traverse through a swampy or marshy area. For the dangers that exist with them, how significantly are they increased due to rain?

I figure there would be more insects, which carry risks, but are the risks significantly worse when it's raining?

Maybe a better question would be, if you had to trek through a swampland, is there a condition where you would be fine with it on a sunny day, which you would no longer do if it was raining?

Assume the rain is medium to heavy, not something like a light drizzle.

For example, does the terrain become even more dangerous and muddy? Or is it negligibly worse? Is it easier for, say, alligators or such fauna to hide easier, or is the raise in water not enough to change this (as in, they would be able to hide enough anyways and this isn't a strong point)? Can flooding happen in a way that it would not normally happen on a sunny day?

There are raised paths you have to walk over.

Comment: Is this a swamp with raised paths or a swamp which you cross walking over less dangerous ground. Or a swamp you cross by boat?

Comment: You mention alligators so I assume you are not in Sweden but as this is a worldwide site, location is also important.

Comment: For widespread rain there is a time lag for the level of standing water (at the lowest altitude) to rise, because of run-off making its way there. A swamp itself doesn't drain much by run-off (or it would not be a swamp).

Comment: @Willeke Raised paths you have to walk over

Comment: I have reopened the question but there is still a lack of information, especially location.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks. Let us suppose it is the southeastern United States for a location, or is that too unspecific? Is there a way I can provide more information? Let me know if I can be more detailed.

Comment: @Water, you can edit all into the question (rather than in a comment and waiting till someone else edits it for you.) If you can give one sample swamp or even one area of one, people can look up the details and help you. Swamps are very different, sometimes even the different parts of one swamp can be different.

Comment: Insects usually are less of a problem when it rains. Most flying insects stay grounded while it rains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Advantages:

- Alligators are cold-blooded, which means they become much less active when it gets colder. According to [this website](https://blog.wildfloridairboats.com/alligators-and-cold-weather) "When temperatures in Florida drop below 80 degrees Fahrenheit [26°C], alligators lose their appetite, and they stop feeding altogether when temperatures hit 73 degrees Fahrenheit [22°C] or lower". So they are going to be less of a threat.
- Mosquitoes *can* fly while it rains, but are usually less active.

Disadvantages:

- Rain makes the ground slippery, so there is a higher risk of slipping and sliding into a mud hole or pond. This should not be that much of a risk if you stay on paths, but would be a risk if you go off-path.
- Rain means worse sight, so it will be easier to get disoriented.
- Cloud cover means it gets dark earlier and much harder to see anything at night.
- Bad weather means less people will be around hiking, so if you need help it's less likely someone will find you by chance.
- Water levels *might* raise. This effect is usually delayed by quite a while after it started raining. But depending on location you might experience sudden flash floods during longer rain periods which might be inconvenient at least and life-threatening at worst. This is very, very dependent on location.

My recommendation would be: **Ask the locals.** If they tell you it's a bad idea, it probably is.